# two functional dependencies are equivalent

Tags: database, dependencies

Now I have two set S1 = {M -> TN, P->QM} S2={M->N,P->Q,P->MT,MN->T}. I need to check whether these two sets have equivalent functional dependencies.

Here is what I had so far:

S+ I can get:

- M->N, M->T (Aug rule,1)
- P->Q, P->M (Aug rule,2)
- P->T(transit rule,3+4)
- P->MT(Additive, 4,5)

But I don't know how to get MN->T in S2. i think it might can use pseudotransitive rule, but I am not sure how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I will not tell you the exact rules (I don't remember it) but:
S1 is:

- M -> TN
- P -> QM

and S2 is:

- M -> N
- P -> Q
- P -> MT
- MN -> T

I can write it as this (Q and MT is dependent on P so it doesn't matter):

- M->N
- P->MQT
- MN->T

Now I know that N is dependent to M so I can put it out from last dependency:

- M->N
- P->MQT
- M->T

So I have this:

- M->NT
- P->MQT

And because I know that T is dependent to M I can exclude it from second dependency:

- M->NT
- P->MQ

So it is the same as S1. Hope It will help.